# (Ubuntu 18.04) (Chromium) (Flash) Plugin is not supported.

Tags: 18.04, flash, chromium, plugins, html

Whenever I open a page with a flash in it, It is replaced with with a white background, writing that says "Plugin not supported", and a grey puzzle piece above the writing.

Any thoughts on how to fix this error?

Comment: How did you install Flash?

Comment: just about every way to install it. through the terminal and everything. but, same problem. and It is already enabled in chromium.

Comment: Possibly you have messed it up somehow, then. The recommended way in Ubuntu to enable Flash for Chromium is to install the `adobe-flashplugin` package. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html Another possibility is that you need to allow Cromium (via some setting in Cromium) to use Flash.

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-chromium.html#id_29382

Comment: I have installed flash via "sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin" same issue.

Comment: about:plugins redirects to chrome://plugins/, and shows "this site cannot be reached" error.

Comment: Also, I have went into chrome settings, content settings, and flash. there seems to be only two options, ask first, and block sites from running. using ask first does not fix the problem.

Comment: I don't have Chromium installed, but I have Chrome, and there I have to allow Flash per site. Maybe it's similar in Chromium. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6258784

Comment: where do I get closed source chrome? It is not available in the Ubuntu software store.

Comment: https://www.google.com/chrome/ But my impression is that it is rather inconvenient nowadays to use Flash on Chrome. If Flash is important to you, and if you are ready to try some other web browser, Firefox might be a better choice. At the moment, that is. Please note that Flash is a deprecated technique, and will not get security updates after 2020. Until then I have the impression that the big web browser developers intend to gradually make it harder to use it.

Answer (score 1):

To enable *Flash* in *Chromium* on *Ubuntu* 18.04, you do **not** install the packages `flashplugin-installer` and/or `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. Instead you need to enable the repository "Canonical Partners" in "Software Properties", then install the package `adobe-flashplugin`.

To test flash support go to https://get.adobe.com/de/flashplayer/about/ and check the small area right of the first text paragraph. It's supposed to provide a box "Version Information"; you may have to click on it to enable the plugin.

As Flash is considered legacy software, and known for security holes galore, I strongly recommend to uninstall it once you're done.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a solution if you still want to use chromium, but going to the google chrome website and downloading the closed source version worked for me. chrome simply updated flash, and now it works without fail.

Comment: I installed Chromium to test, and Flash worked fine for me (the same way as with Chrome with the difference that `adobe-flashplugin` is needed). I have a theory: Is your Chromium possibly installed via a snap?

Comment: See [bug #1771162](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1771162).